# question of function of helm-projectile-find-file

Tags: helm

When using helm-projectile-find-file, if I want to find java file (end by .java). I typed java, but it could also list file of

```
jav/test/a.a
jav/test1/a.a
jav/test2/a.a
```

How to make it work only list the file name whose continuous chars form a "java" word? Also I tried to regular express, such as "java$", but it doesn't work. Any way to support regular express?

Comment: You add a space character at the end for Helm to switch to its usual matching.

Comment: Btw, Helm always gives you all the files that are exactly matched the string you entered at the top. Always. So, the file list of any thing not continuous is always below the candidates with continuous chars. You don't have to worry that some result that contains `java` are scattered randomly in the file list.